# Drop Cap a first letter using html tag

Tags: html, css, text, formatting

Can anyone help me to identify an HTML tag that I can use for writing the first letter of a word in "Drop Cap" form as we do it in MS word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```css
div.first {
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

div.first:first-letter {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"><span class="second">Ž</span>ed Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
<div class="first"><span class="second">Z</span>as Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Comment: You have done it by using Bootstrap, what if we are bound to use just html?

Comment: There is no Bootstrap in the answer

Comment: Actually you have used class="second" its Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS style definition will cause the first letter of all `<p>` tags to be rendered using a larger font and a red color:

```
p::first-letter{
        color: red;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }
```